# CSS getting applied to default menu

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I'm new to sharepoint, they gave me a site, and I want it to look half decent, so I went to w3schools.com to try out some basic codes. When I put this in the content editor in my sharepoint site, it worked well, and it displayed the bar where I put it.

The problem is, it applied it to all the menu, even the default sharepoint menu - ie Insert Webpart, all the editing tools seems to have the CSS applied to it.

How can I restrict the code to just the particular webpart?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
      border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    }
    
    li:last-child {
      border-right: none;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: By showing us the relevant HTML for the target page and a problematic page, and updating your CSS to reference an ID or class (or even element) unique to the page that you want the CSS to appear on.

Comment: Yeah, so how do I reference a different ID or class?

Comment: Let's say your target page has `<body id="good">` and the page you don't want to apply the styles to has `<body id="bad">`. Using `li` would target the `<li>` elements on both pages. Affixing the ID to the selector as `#good li` would only target the `<li>` elements on the good page.

Comment: Thanks I was able to read up on this and found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what @Obsidian Age said, the style needs to reference the ID like

`li#myID {}`

It will then apply it to li tags which have the id "myID"

`li id="myID">`